# Patchwork: why so many buttons?

Tags: patchwork

Playing Patchwork. There seems to be so many button tokens, but we do not seem to be able to end the game with more than 10 buttons in the pocket. All the 10s, 20s just sit there, unused. Are we missing something? How to accumulate more “money”? :)

Answer (score 4):

The most buttons I've ended with has been about 25. However, it would be entirely possible to end up with more if you stopped purchasing more tiles halfway through the game, and used the "Advance and receive buttons" action until the end.

I would not recommend this strategy, as you will likely be left with many holes in your board, which count as -2 buttons each.

Comment: It is certainly possible to end up with more that 25. The first few moves are often crucial.

Comment: Indeed, if you played optimally, and the choices are in your favour, I would think you could end up with at least 40 buttons